# Slicebox showing no error, but still nothing on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code is not showing any error in developer mode, but still not working.
I took it from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_RaXJhcwJE

If you find any error or any mistake, please help me. The code's exactly the same as in the video but I think there might be some bug, or perhaps some additional file is required.

Also if you know how to learn slicebox, or have any source please share it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>sliced image slider</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slicebox/css/demo.css">
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
     <!-- jQuery library -->
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="slicebox/js/modernizr.custom.46884.js"></script>
     <script src="slicebox/js/jquery.slicebox.min.js"></script>
     <style type="text/css">
      .sb-slider{
       margin: 10px auto;
       position: relative;
       overflow: hidden;
       width: 100%;
       list-style: none;
       padding: 0;
      }
      .sb-slider li{
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       display: none;
      }
      .sb-slider li > a{
       outline: none; 
      }
      .sb-slider li > a img{
       border: none;
      }
      .sb-slider img {
       max-width: 100%;
       display: block; 
      }
      .sb-description{
       padding: 20px;
       bottom: 10px;
       left: 10px;
       right: 10px;
       z-index: 2000;
       position: absolute;
       background: #cbbfae;
       background: rgba(190, 176, 155, .4);
       border-left: 4px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
       -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
       filter: alpha(opacity:=0);
       opacity: 0;
       color: white;
       transition: all 200ms;
      }
      .sb-slider li.sb-current .sb-description{
    
       -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=80);
       filter: alpha(opacity:=80);
       opacity: 1;
      }
      .sb-slider li.sb-current .sb-description:hover{
       -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=99);
       filter: alpha(opacity:=99);
       background: rgb(190, 176, 155,.7);
      }
      .sb-perspective{
       position: relative;
      }
      .sb-perspective > div {
       position: absolute;
       transform-style: preserve-3d;
       backface-visibility: hidden;
      } 
      .sb-slide{
       margin: 0;
       display: block;
       position: absolute;
       transform-style: preserve-3d;
      }
      .container{
       margin: 30px;
      }
      .shadow{
       width: 100%;
       height: 168px;
       position: relative;
       margin-top: -100px;
       background: url('slicebox/images/shadow.png') 100% 100%;
       z-index: -1;
       display: none;
      }
      .sb-description h3{
       font-size: 20px;
       text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
      }
      .sb-description h3 a{
       color: #4a3c27;
       text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); 
      }
      .nav-arrows{
       display: none;
      }
      .nav-arrows a{
       width: 42px;
       height: 42px;
       background: #cbbfae url('jw.png') no-repeat top left;
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       left: 2px;
       text-indent: -9000px;
       cursor: pointer;
       margin-top: -21px;
       opacity: 0.9;
       border-radius: 50%;
       box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
      }
      .nav-arows a:first-child{
       left: auto;
       right: 2px;
       background-position: top right;
      }
      .nav-arows a:hover{
       opacity: 1;
      }
      .nav-dots{
       text-align: center;
       position: absolute;
       bottom: -5px;
       height: 30px;
       width: 100%;
       left: 0;
       display: none;
      }
      .nav-dots span{
       display: inline-block;
       width: 16px;
       height: 16px;
       border-radius: 50%;
       margin: 3px;
       background: #cbbfae;
       cursor: pointer;
       box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 
        inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
      }
      .nav-dots span.nav-dot-current{
       box-shadow:  0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6) inset  0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1)
       inset  0 0 0 8px rgba(255,255,255,1)
      }
      .nav-options{
       width: 70px;
       height: 30px;
       position: absolute;
       right: 70px;
       bottom: 0px;
       display: none;
      }
      .nav-options span{
       width: 30px;
       height: 30px;
       background: #cbbfae url('jw.png') no-repeat top left;
       text-indent: -9000px;
       cursor: pointer;
       opacity: 0.7;
       display: inline-block;
       border-radius: 50%;
      }
      .nav-options span:first-child{
       background: -30px 0px;
       margin-right: 3px;
      }
      .nav-options span:hover{
       opacity: 1;
      }
    
    
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
     <br>
     <br>
     <br>
     <br>
     <br>
    
     <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="wrapper">
       <ul class="sb-slider" id="sb-slider col-md-offset-4">
        <li>
         <a href=""><img src="slicebox/images/1.jpg"></a>
         <div class="sb-description">
          <h3>beautiful family</h3>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href=""><img src="slicebox/images/2.jpg"></a>
         <div class="sb-description">
          <h3>beautiful family</h3>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href=""><img src="slicebox/images/3.jpg"></a>
         <div class="sb-description">
          <h3>beautiful family</h3>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href=""><img src="slicebox/images/4.jpg"></a>
         <div class="sb-description">
          <h3>beautiful family</h3>
         </div>
        </li>
        
       </ul>
       <div id="shadow" class="shadow"></div>
       <div id="nav-arrows" class="nav-arrows">
        <a href="">Next</a>
        <a href="">Previous</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    
    
    <script type="text/javaScript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      var page = (function(){
      var $navArrows = $ ('#nav-arrows').hide(),
      $shadow = $('#shadow').hide(),
       slicebox = $('#sb-slider').slicebox({
        onReady : function(){
         $navArrows.show();
         $shadow.show();
        },
        orientation: 'r',
        cuboidsRandom: true,
        disperseFactor: 30
       }),
       init = function(){
        initEvents(); 
       },
       initEvents = function(){
        $navArrows.children(':first').on('click', function(){
         slicebox.next();
         return false;
        });
        $navArrows.children(':last').on('click', function(){
         slicebox.previous();
         return false;
        });
       }; 
    
       return {init  : init};
    
      })();
      page.init();
     });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run the snippet that you gave, this is the error that I saw:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).slicebox is not a function
>   TypeError: $(...).slicebox is not a function

From the error message alone it seems that your problem **is not including the Slicebox plugin as a JS file**.

You need to go to the Slicebox website ([Github](https://github.com/codrops/Slicebox/) in this case), download the *[jquery.slicebox.js](https://github.com/codrops/Slicebox/blob/master/js/jquery.slicebox.js)* file, and then include it in your website as such:
`<script src='jquery.slicebox.js'></script>`

However, as this is from a Snippet, I cannot be sure if you just didn't include the dependency in the snippet, and so it throws me this error.

If not, **what is the error you are seeing** (check the console perhaps)?